# Improve memory usage: IntegerHashMap

Tags: java, dictionary

We use a `HashMap<Integer, SomeType>()` with more than a million entries.  I consider that large.

But integers are their own hash code.  Couldn't we save memory with a, say, `IntegerHashMap<Integer, SomeType>()` that uses a special `Map.Entry`, using int directly instead of a pointer to an `Integer` object? In our case, that would save 1000000x the memory required for an `Integer` object.

Any faults in my line of thought?   Too special to be of general interest? (at least, there is an `EnumHashMap`)

add1. The first generic parameter of `IntegerHashMap` is used to make it closely similar to the other `Map` implementations.  It could be dropped, of course.

add2. The same should be possible with other maps and collections.  For example `ToIntegerHashMap<KeyType, Integer>`, `IntegerHashSet<Integer>`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a "Primitive collections" library.  They are usually much better with memory usage and performance.  One of the oldest/popular libraries was called "Trove".  However, it is a bit outdated now.  The main active libraries in use now are:

- [Goldman Sach Collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections)
- [Fast Util](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/)
- [Koloboke](https://github.com/leventov/Koloboke)

[See Benchmarks Here](http://java-performance.info/large-hashmap-overview-jdk-fastutil-goldman-sachs-hppc-koloboke-trove)

Comment: Best for me would be an (any) implementation of primitive collections as part of JDK / Apache commons / Guava. Using additional libraries isn't easy for me, unfortunately. And speed is not so much my concern, rather memory. Nevertheless, your answer probably is as close as I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Some words of caution:

1. "integers are their own hash code" I'd be very careful with this statement. Depending on the integers you have, the distribution of keys may be anything from optimal to terrible. Ideally, I'd design the map so that you can pass in a custom [`IntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html) as hashing strategy. You can still default this to `(i) -> i` if you want, but you probably want to introduce a modulo factor, or your internal array will be enormous. You may even want to use an [`IntBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html), where one param is the int and the other is the number of buckets.
2. I would drop the first generic param. You probably don't want to implement `Map<Integer, SomeType>`, because then you will have to box / unbox in all your methods, and you will lose all your optimizations (except space). Trying to make a primitive collection compatible with an object collection will make the whole exercise pointless.

Comment: good point in response to the "integers are their own hash code" statement. For simplicity, I would build in a proper hash method for integers. But as you would use a secific `Map.Key` object, that could be done, too.

Comment: @UlrichScholz I thought the whole point was to avoid objects as much as possible. But that depends on what your use cases are.

Comment: Sure I want to avoid unnecessary objects. Avoiding them as much as possible is a different thing.
I'm not familiar with the details of the current `HashMap` implementation. But it should well be possible to have `IntegerHashMap` follow it closely, except for using `int` keys, together with a proper hash function. (Maybe even the same as implemented with `Integer`).

Comment: Apparently, the `hashcode()` method of the `Integer` class just returns its primitive value. So "integers are their own hash code" may be not that wrong in the end

Comment: @UlrichScholz again, that depends on the distribution of ints you are dealing with and how you are assigning them to buckets. Let's say all your ints are multiples of 1024 and 1024 is also the modulo you use for bucket distribution, then that's pretty much the worst case scenario